# FLOP efficiency in CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvprof

According to the definition of `flop_sp_efficiency`

> Ratio of achieved to peak single-precision floating-point operations

The CUDA manual covers FLOPS, [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/achievedflops.htm). The metric yields ratio, e.g. 10%. That raises two questions about the term "peak":

1- Is that a hardware specific value? Therefore, nvprof should be aware of that in order to calculate the ratio and the denominator should be constant for all applications run on a specific device? According to the manual, that is `No_CUDA_cores * Graphic_clock_freq * 2`. Is that the way that nvprof set the denominator?

2- Does that mean the peak value is achieved during the runtime of the program per kernel? Assume a kernel is invoked 10 times. One invocation has the highest FLOPS (has no relation with the hardware value), e.g. 2GFLOPS. Then the efficiency is calculated as `sum(FLOPS_i)/10` which gives the average FLOPS of 10 invocations and then this average is divided by 2 and that yields the FLOPS efficiency for that kernel. With this assumption, a kernel may reaches 2 GFLOPS while another kernel may reach 4 GFLOPS. I say that because the metric is reported per kernel in nvprof.

Any comment on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NVPROF (and other CUDA profilers) calculate FLOPS by replaying the kernel two times. In one pass the tool collects time and SM elapsed cycles. In the second pass the tool modifies the kernel to calculate the total number of FLOPS.

```
SMCOUNT = CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT

flops_sp_efficiency = flop_count_sp / (elapsed_cycles_sm * SM_MAX_FLOP_PER_CYCLE)
SM_MAX_FLOP_PER_CYCLE = CUDA_CORES x 2 / SMCOUNT

flops = flop_count_sp / gpu__time_duration x NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND

gpuclk_hz = elapsed_cycles_sm / SMCOUNT / gpu_time_duration x NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND
```

elapsed_cycles_sm is the number of cycles elapsed in the SM clock domain summed across all SMs. The SM clock domain is the same as the graphics clock.

NVPROF has neither and event nor a metric for time duration. Time duration can be captured in NVPROF using the trace activity. In Perfworks the metric gpu__time_duration is the wall clock duration of the kernel.

Nsight VSE CUDA Profiler allows the developer to customize the weights per instruction or define completely new experiments using SASS regex. See https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/Nsight_Visual_Studio_Edition_User_Guide.htm#Analysis/Report/CudaExperiments/KernelLevel/AchievedFlops.htm

ANSWER 1 - Yes, the tools use real-time measurement to determine the theoretical maximum. This is calculated in a replay of the kernel.

ANSWER 2 - The metric is collected for each execution of a kernel. NVPROF (but not other tools) rolls up the metrics over kernels with the same function name using a non-weighted average.

Comment: The max flop you mentioned is different from the manual. At least you didn't talk about graphic frequency. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Also, with that formula, the M2000 which has 6 multiprocssor and 128 cores per MP, reaches 768*2/6 = 256 FLOPS for one SM. Since there are 6 SMs, then the peak FLOPS is 1536. I think the unit (M/G/T) is missing then.

Comment: M2000 has a theoretical maximum of 256 FLOP/cycle/SM. Multiply by SMCOUNT = 1536 FLOP/cycle. Multiply by graphics (boost or base) clock frequency (~1163 MHz)  = 1.78 TFLOPS.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the defition of "FLOPS" is [the number of floating point operations per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS), where multiply-add operations can be counted as one or two "ops". nvprof will simply use the peak Flop-rate of the device in the efficiency calculation which it determines based on the properties of the device (i.e. the number of ALUs) and the frequency the device reports (I do not believe it measures the actual frequency in real-time).
2. FLOPS is already a time-average (and will clearly vary over the execution of a single kernel), so when reported on a per-kernel basis than it is also an average over all invocations of the kernel in question.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence `it is also an average over all kernel instances`, I think you assume all invocations of that kernels and not all kernels since the latter is meaningless.